# Generating a Pandas Dataframe Using Different Length of Dictionary Outputs and Aligning Same Keys into Same Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have an output such as dictionary-formatted elements in a list:

```
[list([('social', 8), ('drives', 3), ('prep', 12), ('function', 5)])
 list([('social', 10), ('conj', 8), ('ppron', 7), ('i', 7)])
 list([('pronoun', 12), ('ppron', 10), ('i', 7), ('drives', 8)])
 list([('affiliation', 6), ('function', 55), ('pronoun', 19), ('ppron', 16)])
```

Specifically, this partial output came from the below codes (i.e. counting the number of occurrences of each keyword over a set of rows from Pandas Dataframe data set; note that the actual data set has more than 4 rows but for simplicitiy, I limited it to 4 here).

```
from collections import Counter

#LIWC Features Extraction
liwc =[] 
for item in data.tokens:
    counts = list(Counter(category for token in item for category in parse(token)).items())
    liwc.append(counts)
liwc_ = np.array(liwc)
print (liwc_)
```

What I am trying to do is to create a Pandas Dataframe which includes all the possible keys as column names and insert the corresponding values into column values such as below. The key here is to align same keys into same columns.

```
social drives prep function conj ppron i pronoun affiliation 
8      3      12   5        0    0     0 0       0
10     0      0    0        8    7     7 0       0
0      8      0    0        0    10    7 12      0
0      0      0    55       0    16    0 19      6
```

Comment: Please double check your input, this is not valid python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```py
data = [
    [("social", 8), ("drives", 3), ("prep", 12), ("function", 5)],
    [("social", 10), ("conj", 8), ("ppron", 7), ("i", 7)],
    [("pronoun", 12), ("ppron", 10), ("i", 7), ("drives", 8)],
    [("affiliation", 6), ("function", 55), ("pronoun", 19), ("ppron", 16)],
]

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(l) for l in data]).fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   social  drives  prep  function  conj  ppron    i  pronoun  affiliation
0     8.0     3.0  12.0       5.0   0.0    0.0  0.0      0.0          0.0
1    10.0     0.0   0.0       0.0   8.0    7.0  7.0      0.0          0.0
2     0.0     8.0   0.0       0.0   0.0   10.0  7.0     12.0          0.0
3     0.0     0.0   0.0      55.0   0.0   16.0  0.0     19.0          6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

One option using the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor directly, just [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)  [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) to each sublist:

```
lst = [list([('social', 8), ('drives', 3), ('prep', 12), ('function', 5)]),
       list([('social', 10), ('conj', 8), ('ppron', 7), ('i', 7)]),
       list([('pronoun', 12), ('ppron', 10), ('i', 7), ('drives', 8)]),
       list([('affiliation', 6), ('function', 55), ('pronoun', 19), ('ppron', 16)])]

out = pd.DataFrame(map(dict, lst)).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Output:

```
   social  drives  prep  function  conj  ppron  i  pronoun  affiliation
0       8       3    12         5     0      0  0        0            0
1      10       0     0         0     8      7  7        0            0
2       0       8     0         0     0     10  7       12            0
3       0       0     0        55     0     16  0       19            6
```